# Iterate over rows of Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have df like:

```
CELLID  lon       lat         METER           LATITUDE_SM LONGITUDE_SM  Path_ID
2557709 5.286339 51.353820 E0047000004028217  51.3501      5.3125    2557709_E0047000004028217
```

For each Path_ID(str) I would like to iterate the loop and would like to achieve df1 like:

```
Path_ID                    METER          LATITUDE_SM  LONGITUDE_SM
2557709_E0047000004028217 E0047000004028217  51.3501    5.3125 
Path_ID                   CELLID            Lon           lat
2557709_E0047000004028217 2557709         5.286339     51.353820
```

I have many rows in the df. 
I am doing something like

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    print row ['Path_ID'],row['METER'],row['LATITUDE_SM'], row ['LONGITUDE_SM']
```

Comment: If you already have the `df` why are you using a loop to print it out? Does `print(df)` not suffice?

Comment: I want to have latitude longitude of meter for path_ID , and for same path_id latitude longitude of CELLID. so basically split it into two raws for a complete data frame

Comment: If you truly want to print row by row, see jpp's solution. But you can likely save yourself a lot of time by just printing a subset of the dataframe, where you slice the columns you want. `print(df[['Path_ID', 'CEILID', 'Lon', 'lat']])` for instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very hard to understand your goal, but IIUC, you want to group by `Path_ID` and print each value

```
grouped_df= df.groupby("Path_ID")[["Path_ID", "METER", "LATITUDE_SM", "LONGITUDE_SM"]]
for key, val in grouped_df:
    print grouped_df.get_group(key), "\n"
```

Output

```
                     Path_ID              METER  LATITUDE_SM  LONGITUDE_SM
0  2557709_E0047000004028217  E0047000004028217        51.35        5.3125
```

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear why you want this behaviour, but you can achieve this with `pd.DataFrame.iloc`.

If you only need specific columns, replace `:` with a list of column numbers.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5, 5)))

for i in range(len(df.index)):
    print(df.iloc[[i], :])

#           0         1         2         3         4
# 0  0.587349  0.947435  0.974285  0.498303  0.135898
#           0         1         2         3         4
# 1  0.292748  0.880276  0.522478  0.081902  0.187494
#           0         1         2         3         4
# 2  0.692022  0.908397  0.200202  0.099722  0.348589
#           0         1         2         3         4
# 3  0.041564  0.980425  0.899634  0.725757  0.569983
#           0         1         2         3         4
# 4  0.787038  0.000077  0.213646  0.444095  0.022923
```